# Is GFCI an adjective or a noun?

Tags: word-usage

In home improvement, you often see words like "built-in" or "polyurethane" used as nouns.   These are plainly missing a word (cabinet and paint, respectively) and it drives me nuts.

GFCI stands for "Ground Fault Circuit Interruptor" and refers to a device which interrupts the electrical circuit if it detects a ground fault. They come in a variety of packages: integrated as part of a circuit breaker, switch, receptacle, or a standalone device. From any of these locations, the GFCI device can confer protection to other outlets.   Most people casually know them as receptacles with a "Test" and "Reset" button, and many think that's the only kind, so they see no need to disambiguate which kind.

My view is that GFCI is an adjective which needs a noun such as "receptacle", "circuit breaker" or just "device". Others think GFCI works as a noun.

Which is it? Is their usage improper, or am I being overly formal?

Comment: I would think of GFCI as a noun; all the four component words are nouns. Adding a fifth noun doesn't stop the whole thing still being a compound noun.

Comment: It's a nominal functioning as attributive modifier of "device". Not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective!

Comment: When choosing items do you ever say, “i’ll take two reds and one blue”?  Or “1 chicken and two beef”?  Do you always say pickup truck and never just pickup?  If you’re coloring do you ever say “Gimme that green” without the “crayon”?  Or “They come in white or black.  I like the white.”

Comment: Polyurethane is a compound that is added to things like stains. Definitely a noun on its own. The stain contains polyurethane.  Definitely not an adjective.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it’s a noun not an adjective. While all adjectives modify nouns (or noun phrases, if you prefer), not all things that modify nouns are adjectives. It takes quite a bit more than that to call a word an adjective.

Terms like *GCFI receptacle, GCFI circuit breaker, GCFI device* are compound nouns where each piece is itself a noun.

For the matter, so too is *circuit breaker*. One way that you can easily tell that a word like *circuit* is not an adjective because it accepts only adjectives or other nouns as modifiers, not intensifiers like *very*.  You cannot have a ✻*very circuit breaker*, only an *easy circuit breaker* or *closed circuit breaker* — or here, a *GCGI circuit breaker*.

Another test for such things is to see what happens when you use them predicatively instead of attributively.  That means using the thing you’re checking whether is an adjective after an inflection of *be* as with ✻*The breaker is circuit*, which clearly doesn’t work.

A third test is to see whether the word is gradable. You can’t have *a ✻more circuit breaker* or *a ✻circuiter breaker*. Same with your GCFI: it’s not possible for one circuit breaker to be any “more GCFI” or “GCFIer” than another.

So it’s a noun.

Comment: Hidden in the OP is the intimation that GFCI (which *is* a "complete" well-attested noun) is used as an adjective quite often (breaker, receptacle, device are what might be called "form factors"). This is the typical noun-as adjective. Perhaps you can address that: it seems to be the crux of the question.

Comment: @Yorik This has all been addressed before, many times. Along with the fact that some classifying adjectives like 'nuclear' pass almost all the tests-for-nouns given above, and that the debate is still ongoing as to whether say 'steel in 'steel bridge' has converted.

Comment: @Yorik But that is not an adjective. That's the whole point. Merely modifying a noun doesn’t make something an adjective. This is the misunderstanding.

Comment: It isn't really the whole point. You are kind of glossing over the "attributive noun" part. What people such as the OP is calling an adjective. I suppose my point is that the OP might not accept your answer without addressing that more explicitly. The OP is part peeving and part asking what the distinction is. As far as it being addressed many times, perhaps this should have been flagged as duplicate.